# how to show busy indicator when one click on a item of a list box having more than 6000 items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

In one of my MVC3 projects using jquery with knockoutjs, where I am using knockoutjs to bind a List Box.

When the list box has a few items, a click on an item immediately selects the item, but when the List Box has a lot of items (6000+), it takes 10-15 seconds to select the item.

The user is not aware what is happening in those 10-15 seconds, so we thought to implement a busy indicator.

Is this possible? Is there a event for this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried to profile your code to know exactly what is taking so much time? You could determine where the bottlenecks are and either fix them or you could be able to know how you can show a busy indicator. Without more information, it's hard to tell you how to do.

Comment: Why ask a question if you can't bother to check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

If the `select` element is using the `options` binding, it may be because the binding is getting updated each time you click. You can try upgrading to either version 2.3.0 or 3.0.0 beta that were both just released. I'm quite sure that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next construction for this
**ViewModel**

```
var viewModel = new function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(); // your items
    self.waitingResponse = ok.observable(false); // true - when you are waiting for response
    self.sendRequest = function() 
    {
       self.waitingResponse(true); // this will hide table with items
                                   // and disaplay "Waiting for response..."
       $.ajax(
       {
          // 
          complete: function() 
          {
             self.waitingResponse(false); // this will display table with items
                                          // and hide "Waiting for response..."
          }
       })
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div data-bind="visible : waitingResponse()">
    <span>Waiting for response...</span>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible : !waitingResponse()">
    <table>
        <!-- table with items -->
    </table>
</div>
```